# Passing a value into a form field using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Can figure out why this isn't working.

I'm calling the function drawgraph(z) like this:
    drawgraph("t")

```
function drawgraph(z) {
var v = document.getElementById("frmvar");
alert(z);
v.value = z;
function handleResponse(response) {
   ajaxResponse = response;
   }
draw(handleResponse); 
};
```

The HTML form filed looks like this:

```
<input type="test" name="frmvar">
```

The alert box springs up with t in it

I get the following error message:

> TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'v.value = z')

Can see what I'm doing wrong! Someone help me please

Thanks

Chris

Comment: easy - use `id="frmvar"` in addition to `name="frmvar"`, as you're using `getElementById()` in your JavaScript ;)

Comment: I think you are missing some code? What is the draw function?

Comment: Also, what's type="test"?

Comment: @ZathrusWriter, that's not good advice. The form wont get submitted correctly if he removed the name attribute.

Comment: @Prisoner true, I've rephrased my comment, thank you :)

Comment: @Zathrus ... ahhhh I need a name in there as I'm passing it can't see the wood for the trees, Thanks

Comment: Define `Id` two input can have similar names but `Id` is what differentiate two controls,thing is you are fetching element by id not by name so assign an id to your control.Why downvotes i do not understand this question may be simple but suffice  requirement for a question .

Comment: @SurajSingh I can't speak about others' motivations, but this question is not useful for the site. Most typeErrors are not caused by confusing `id` with `name`. Also, reading the documentation should be sufficient to cast enough light to the problem to not need to ask here.

Comment: @JanDvorak seriously useful for site ? I don't believe in this theory of yours i must say that, a simple comment on that question can do that and flag it for moderators to close this question as its a free cookie for anyone who answers. But downvoting ain't gonna help .

Comment: @SurajSingh I did vote to close. What can I do more?

Comment: I know what I can do: bypass the non-working close vote queue and just dump closevote requests to a relevant chat room. Too bad I didn't do it sooner.

Comment: @Jan What a high handed attitude to take, I genuinely had been looking at this for ages trying to see where I was going wrong, just needed a fresh pair of eyes to point out the obvious. I don't know what this up voting / downvoting system is I just needed some help and I find it amazing you're saying I shouldn't ask for any. Next time you ask for help think back to this post. Thanks to all who did help and point out the obvious to me!

Comment: @CHRISLEONARD if you want help that is teporary in nature, use the chat (you need 20 rep though). We'll be more than glad to help you. Please do note the point of this site is to build a knowledge base, not to find everyone's little typos. If our purpose was to provide second pairs of eyes,  our questions would not be saved for generations to come. Those "need a pair of eyes" questions distract from the ones that really need some expert attention and make them harder  to find.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use:

```
var v = document.getElementById("frmvar");
```

you need to assign an `id` to your HTML element.

```
<input type="text" name="frmvar" id="frmvar">
```

Comment: Small note: I think you mean `type="text"`

Comment: @Shabab it is text, I'd already edited it.

Comment: Should it be be some of check if `getElementById()` returns `null`?

Answer (score 1):

```
function drawgraph(z) {
var v = document.getElementById("frmvar");
alert(z);
v.value = z;
function handleResponse(response) {
   ajaxResponse = response;
   }
draw(handleResponse); 
};
```

You have to mention Id  as **frmvar** to use getElementByID.

```
<input type="text" Id="frmvar" name="frmvar">
```